# Biztalk custom functoid unlogical error in mapping

Tags: c#, dictionary, customization, biztalk

I started building some custom date functoids for biztalk.

I deployed the custom functoid class, and added it to the custom functoid list in the biztalk mapper.

My mapping is like this:
https://kurdy.de/owncloud/index.php/s/Law7vCB9lfLkg8J

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var ScriptNS0" version="1.0" xmlns:ns0="http://testdeleteme1.Output" xmlns:ScriptNS0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/ScriptNS0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/ns0:Datum" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/ns0:Datum">
    <ns0:Datum>
      <xsl:for-each select="Testfalle">
        <Testfalle>
          <xsl:variable name="var:v1" select="ScriptNS0:DatetimeToCustomDatetime(string(Datum/text()) , string(Format/text()))" />
          <Datum>
            <xsl:value-of select="$var:v1" />
          </Datum>
          <xsl:if test="Format">
            <Format>
              <xsl:value-of select="Format/text()" />
            </Format>
          </xsl:if>
        </Testfalle>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ns0:Datum>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My functoid expects 2 parameters, the first is a c# datetime as a string, the second is the expected target format format as string.

for example param1="2015-09-15T20:15:13.000", param2="yyyyMMdd"
the function of the functoid itself is working in a common console application. it gives me an "20150915".

but in the biztalk mapping i get 2 errors.
If I debug the map:

> "Error 3   Exception Caught: Value does not fall within the expected range."

If I test the map:

> "Error 3   XSL transform error: Unable to write output instance to the >following [fileLocation]. Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: extension"

The code of my functoid is:

```
    public string DatetimeToCustomDatetime(string date, string dateFormat)
    {
         DateTime dt;
         string retVal;
         ResourceManager resmgr = new ResourceManager("Custom.Biztalk.Datefunctoid" + ".DatetimeResources",  Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
         CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

         dateFormat =  dateFormat.Trim();
         dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);

         try
         {
             retVal = dt.ToString(dateFormat);
         }
         catch (Exception myEx)
         {
             throw new  Exception(string.Format(resmgr.GetString("IDS_PERIMETERFUNCTOID_EXCEPTION"))  + date + " " + dateFormat + "\n" + myEx.Message);
         }
         return retVal;
     }
```

Can you help me? I do really have no clue where the problem may be...

I already built a custom functoid which works. It converts a customdatetime to a c# datetime and works, it is built nearly the same except the name and the functoid id.

SOLVED:
            SetExternalFunctionName(GetType().Assembly.FullName
                    , "BIS.Custom.Functoid.DatetimeToAnyDatetime"
                    , "DatetimeToCustomDatetime");

I set a wrong namespace in this from the BaseFunctoid inherited function.

Comment: Found the error, I had a wrong Namespace. Shame on me.

Comment: Just had the same problem - thanks for posting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: SetExternalFunctionName(GetType().Assembly.FullName , "BIS.Custom.Functoid.DatetimeToAnyDatetime" , "DatetimeToCustomDatetime");

I set a wrong namespace in this from the BaseFunctoid inherited function.

Further Information in main post.